# change url on scrolling using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change url when scrolling bar  without using # . this is my code:-

```
<a class = "section"
    href = "#first" > First paragraph < /a> < p > < /p> < a class = "section"
    href = "#second" > Second paragraph < /a> < p > < /p> < a class = "section"
    href = "#third" > Third paragraph < /a> < p > < /p> < a class = "section"
    href = "#fourth" > Fourth paragraph < /a>

    function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
        var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
        var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
        var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();
        return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
    }

    $(window).scroll(function(e) {
        var anchors = $('.section');
        for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; ++i) {
            if (isScrolledIntoView(anchors[i])) {
                var href = $(anchors[i]).attr('href');
                location.hash = href.slice(href.indexOf('#') + 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    $(function() {
        var hash = location.hash;
        if (hash) {
            // Scroll to the element with the given hash.
            var anchors = $('.section');
            for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; ++i) {
                if ($(anchors[i]).attr('href') === hash) {
                    $(window).scrollTop($(anchors[i]).offset().top);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

when i run this code my url show like this:

```
file:///C:/Users/jony/Desktop/demo.html#third
```

but I want to show like this :

```
file:///C:/Users/jony/Desktop/demo.html/third
```

Comment: That's not possible without `#` you can have `#/third` but not just `/third`

Comment: @mohamedrias if you check this url https://baggu.com/ this is exact functionality which I want

Comment: Why you want to remove the hash ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history esp `pushState`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I have checked many posts and articles for pushstate and history.js but they all have very little documention and I dont know how to apply this to my code.

Comment: What do you mean by "very little documentation"? You can use `history.pushState` method to change url without reloading your page. How much more "documentation" do you need?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new history entry (i.e. user can click back button to go back), use

```
window.history.pushState(state, title, newURL);
```

otherwise, use

```
window.history.replaceState(state, title, newURL);
```

If you don't know what to do with state and title, you can pass null or empty string.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history